# Wordpress post image path

Tags: image, wordpress, path

I am trying to get the path to the first image in a wordpress post. I am trying to implement a little JQuery zoom effect. $thumbID returns the image's thumbnail. I want this

```
a href='http://hahadb.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/armor-failx640.jpg'
```

to point to the original attached images because it's bigger than the thumb, which will work very well for the zoom effect. Currently I only have 2 posts, each with an attached image.

```
<div class="preview"><a href='http://hahadb.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/armor-failx640.jpg' class = 'cloud-zoom' id='zoom1'
            rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY:-4"><?php echo "$thumbID"; ?></a></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `$thumbID` coming from, would help to get some idea of how you're fetching the post images to begin with. **NOTE:** ob_% functions alongside regex are far from being an ideal solution..

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. :D Cool function:

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```